# Android NDK and Msys

Tags: android-ndk, msys

Can someone please tell me how to work with android NDK and Msys.Is there any setting that needs to be done before I start? And where should i start from?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use msys? Officially it is not supported.

Actually starting from NDK r7 you don't need nor Cygwin, nor Msys to compile under Windows. NDK r7 includes bat file ndk-build.cmd that you can run from cmd.exe command-line. Only issue with it is that you are not allowed to have directory on your PATH with space symbol. Until this is fixed stick to the Cygwin. When this will be fixed (I presume in NDK r8) you will be able to compile in usual Windows command-line.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-MinGW-(Minimalist-Gnu-C/C%2B%2B-Compiler)-on-Microsoft-Windows) to help you install msys in your system. and then you can use it to run your commands.